# How to make appender on daily time basis?

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

I have an appender having size and time based rolling policy, can any one tell how to make it on the daily basis rolling size doesn't matter?

```
<appender name="POS"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/POS/terminal-pos-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>TERMINAL ID [%X{terminalId}] %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

time based rolling policy :

```
<appender name="POS" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${log.folder}/POS/terminal-pos-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <FileNamePattern>>${log.folder}/POS/terminal-pos-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.%i.gz</FileNamePattern>
        <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>TERMINAL ID [%X{terminalId}] %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

You can check the rolling policy in startup log :

```
INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern...
INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Roll-over at midnight.
INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Setting initial period to ...
```

time and size based rolling policy

```
<appender name="POS" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${log.folder}/POS/terminal-pos-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <FileNamePattern>>${log.folder}/POS/terminal-pos-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.%i.gz</FileNamePattern>
        !-- rollover daily -->
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 50MB -->
            <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>TERMINAL ID [%X{terminalId}] %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Comment: can it will work for daily based logs, as i am mentioning date only and not sized only

Comment: The 1st prop is date based only and daily based

Comment: it's the combination of `TimeBasedRollingPolicy`class and the date pattern in the `FileNamePattern` element which determines the rolling frequency